# CSS margin / padding not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to push my footer further down on a lower resolution screen. 
Currently the form I have on the page overlaps into the footer on a 1024x768 resolution screen, on a larger screen this is not a problem as there is plenty of space.

[**page**](http://verifiedfeedback.com/b2b/company/register)

I'm baffled by this and have tried a few solutions all to no avail :

- used padding top in the footer div
- used margin top in the footer div
- used `<br />` tags to make breaks
- made a div `<div style="height:100px;width:100%;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;">`

all of these only had an affect, where the affect is actually below the footer
I need the affect to be above the footer.

Comment: Please post your code here. Once the problem is solved, the link (and thus the question) no longer have any use.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your meaning BenM

Comment: Share your CSS and HTML here. Also put together a jsFiddle > www.jsfiddle.net. By linking directly to the problematic site, when the problem is fixed, we won't see what changed...

Comment: should i paste all the page's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please share the code so others can see it in the future!

Alas...

Your issue is because of this line in your CSS

```
#outer_wrap { height: 120% !important; }
```

It looks like it's being generated by a file called "register". I very rarely set a height like that (what if your at some point overflows this box?), and I've never set a height greater than 100%, it's just asking for problems.

If you remove that line, your page will render properly and you won't have that overflow into the footer.

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/hTruA/] removing that line fixes the problem, for the record, I myself, did not do the css for the site